# jQuery contents with find on iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, find

I use jQuery `contents();` with `find();` on `iframe.someClass` element by code below:

```
$('.someClass').contents().find('a').on('mousedown', function(event) {
    alert('works');
});
```

But this code only doesn't work in IE10. How rebuild this code for works in IE too?

Comment: This should have worked in IE10, I doubt that you document mode might have changed to "Quirks mode".  So please take a look at it in your IE developer tool

Comment: I found solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4378387/182823 Works in IE after loaded iframe (onload)